Maui iOS release build crashes, debug works fine
I am attempting to Run a release build directly on my mac to the iPhone simulator. I use Rollbar in my app, which works fine in Debug but crashes on startup in the Release build. I believe this is something to do with how Maui interacts with Rollbar, but it's not a Rollbar issue per se, especially because everything works fine in Debug. I have tried every permutation of Optimize, Linker, etc.
Run error - https://pastebin.com/gu0MVjct
Here are my CSPROJ Settings (every combination I tried is commented) :
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <ApplicationTitle>Deliberate Creation</ApplicationTitle>
<!--    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>-->
<!--    <Optimize>False</Optimize>-->
<!--    <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>-->
<!--    <MtouchUseLlvm>False</MtouchUseLlvm>-->
<!--      <UseInterpreter>True</UseInterpreter>-->
<!--     <MtouchUseLlvm>False</MtouchUseLlvm>-->
<!--    <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>-->
    
<!--    <MtouchEnableAot>true</MtouchEnableAot>-->
<!--    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>-->

    <CodesignKey>My Certificate Name</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>Apple Distribution Provision Profile</CodesignProvision>
  </PropertyGroup>

In MauiProgram, I have defined the DI service as follows:
mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IErrorLogger, RollbarLogger>();
My service is defined as follows:
using Rollbar;
using Rollbar.DTOs;
using Exception = System.Exception;
using MyProjectName.Helpers;

namespace MyProjectName.Services.Implementation;

public class RollbarLogger : IErrorLogger
{
    public RollbarLogger()
    {

#if DEBUG
        var config = new RollbarLoggerConfig(
            " ***rollbar API key**** ",
            "development");
#else
        var config = new RollbarLoggerConfig(
            " ***rollbar API key**** ",
            "production");
#endif

        RollbarLocator.RollbarInstance.Configure(config);
    }

These are my nugets:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.92" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.92" />
<PackageReference Include="Rollbar" Version="5.2.2" />


Can you try using a try-catch block and see if you get a more specific exception?

Even though everything works fine in Debug, I could not get Rollbar to play nice with Maui in Release. I didn't want to waste more time on this to figure out what is happening in Release, so I switched to Sentry, and everything works flawlessly.

Even though everything works fine in Debug, I could not get Rollbar to play nice with Maui 8.0.92 in Release. I didn't want to waste more time on this to figure out what is happening in Release, so I switched to Sentry, and everything works flawlessly.
